# Как узнать к какому региону памяти процесса принадлежит адрес? С++

Tags: c++, winapi, память, процесс

Предположим пользователь передает в WinAPI Функцию `ReadProcessMemory()` адрес, по которому нужно считать память. Перед использованием этой функции я хочу узнать, возможно ли это вообще. Для этого я могу использовать WinAPI функцию `VirtualQueryEx()`, чтобы узнать доступен ли регион для записи. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю базовый адрес региона, к которому относится переданный адрес. Его можно узнать, перебрав все границы регионов и вычислив, к какому относится данный адрес. Но я уверен, что есть какие-то другие пути решения, хотелось бы узнать о них. К сожалению, в WinAPI документации какой-либо функции, которая делает что-то подобное я не нашел

Comment: Если процесс свой, проверяют доступ на R/W регионов функции `IsBadReadPtr()` и `IsBadWritePtr()` из Kernel32.dll. Их аргументами являются "указатель + размер блока". Если-же процесс чужой и у вас достаточно прав, можно переназначить атрибуты памяти через `VirtualProtectEx()`. А функции `VirtualQueryEx()` не обязательно передавать базу - она сама выравнивает адрес на границу вирт.страницы, т.е. сбрасывает в нуль 12 мл.бит. Все эти функции работают с древом VAD процесса (Virtual Address Descriptor).

Comment: @PRODIGY Спасибо большое, то что надо, я не смог найти подобные нюансы в документации по WinAPI

Comment: @PRODIGY пользуясь случаем хочется задать другой вопрос. В документации по `VirtualQueryEx()` сказано, что значение адреса, передаваемого в нее, округляется до значения следующей страницы региона. А что, если адрес находится внутри последней страницы региона? Получается, мы получим из-за округления информацию о следующем регионе?

Comment: Да, fn округляет до сл.страницы (непонятно зачем). Но при передачи адреса вы можете сами округлить его к началу текущей страницы - просто сделайте выравнивание своего адреса на 4К границу при помощи `AND address,0xfffff000` (сбросить 12 мл.бит) и всё.

Comment: @PRODIGY спасибо. Возможно дебильный вопрос, но никак не могу сообразить почему именно 12 бит. Я догадываюсь, что это потому, что страницы в системах имеют фиксированный размер в 4КБ? Получается, что каждые 0x00001000 адресов, начиная с нуля - это новая страница в памяти и, как я понимаю, они являются минимальной возможной выделяемой единицей памяти для процесса?

Comment: @PRODIGY и такой же дебильный вопрос: даже если мы сами выровняли адрес до адреса виртуальной страницы. Мы же не получим адрес региона, мы получим адрес страницы, в которой лежит наш исходный адрес

Comment: `>>> но никак не могу сообразить почему именно 12 бит` - всё правильно вы понимаете. Страницы юзера начинаются с адреса `0х10000` (резерв по 64К снизу и сверху), и дальше следуют с шагом `0х1000`, т.к. дефолтный размер их 4К, или 12-бит. При выделении региона `VirtualAlloc()` всегда выравнивает блок на эту границу.

Comment: `>>> Мы же не получим адрес региона, мы получим адрес страницы` - неверно! Вы передаёте в `VirtualQuery()` свой\выровненный на 4К любой адрес, а в поле "AllocationBase" структуры ```MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION``` функция возвращает вам базу региона, в который входит ваша страница.

Comment: @PRODIGY спасибо за развернутые ответы. Вы даже ответили на вопросы, которые я не задавал, но очень хотел) И последний вопрос, в документации по WinAPI очень скудно написано отличие `AllocationBase`, который вы упомянули, от `BaseAdress` в структуре `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`. Можете прояснить ситуацию? Если AllocationBase - это базовый адрес региона в котором содержится адрес, переданный в `VirtualQueryEx()`, то что тогда `BaseAdress`? Логически рассуждая, могу предположить, что это базовый адрес страницы, а не региона, в которой содержится наш адрес?

Comment: Вообще, на основе этих комментариев можно написать вполне развернутый ответ. Может, кто нибудь это сделает? Это было бы прекрасно...

Comment: @S.H. попробовал структурировать всю полученную информацию от PRODIGY

Answer (score 1):

По просьбе S.H. попробую сформировать все, что понял из комментариев выше, в один ответ.

В общем случае за информацию о регионах и страницах виртуальной памяти отвечает структура `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`, которая заполняется при вызове функции `VirtualQueryEx()` (или `VirtualQuery()`, если это наш процесс, согласно документации):

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
if (!VirtualQueryEx(process_handle, any_adress, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION))) {
    // Делаем что-то, если считать информацию не удалось
}
```

В `VirtualQueryEx` передаваемый адрес, несмотря на документацию, не обязан быть базовым адресом региона или страницы. Мы можем передать абсолютно любой адрес. Внутри самой функции, согласно документации, он будет округлен до адреса следующей страницы.

Если мы зачем-то очень сильно хотим получить адрес страницы в которой находится наш адрес, то мы можем сбросить 12 младших бит нашего адреса в 0 и получим базовый адрес страницы, содержащий наш адрес:

```
// Не знаю насколько reinterpret_cast уместен, просто первое
// Что пришло в голову
int i = 155;
size_t our_adress = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&i); // К указателям нельзя применять бинарные операции, поэтому не придумал ничего лучше
our_adress &= ~0xFFF;
void* our_ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(our_adress);
std::cout << "Page with base adress " << our_ptr << " has variable by adress " << &i << std::endl;
```

Это связано с тем, что размер виртуальной страницы фиксирован и составляет 4КБ. Иными словами, каждые `0x1000` адресов - это новая виртуальная страница. Не считая диапазон адресов от `0x00000` по `0x10000` и столько же сверху. Это резерв по 64КБ. Из-за него любые первые записи в память процесса начинаются с адреса `0x10000`.

При заполнении `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` функцией `VirtualQueryEx()` мы получаем базовый адрес страницы и базовый адрес региона, в которых содержался переданный в функцию адрес, в полях `BaseAdress` и `AlocationBase` соответственною

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> в документации по WinAPI очень скудно написано отличие

Оказывается на MSDN ошибка в описании `VirtualQuery()`. Сейчас посмотрел в отладчике и как выяснилось, она выравнивает ваш адрес не на следующую страницу, а на начало текущей. То-есть вам не нужно самому сбрасывать 12-младших бит, fn сама это делает.

Пусть регион состоит из 16-ти страниц начиная с `0х10000` и до `0x20000`, а ваш адрес попадает на середину пятой страницы `0х15800`. Тогда в поле **"BaseAddress"** выходной структуры вы получите `0x15000`, а в поле **"AllocationBase"** `0x10000`. Кстати страницы могут быть и не 4КБ, а например 2МБ, 4МБ или даже 1ГБ (зависит от бита[4] PSE в регистре CR4, и бита[8] IA32_EFER.LME). Это будет влиять на возвращаемые значения. Размер страницы в системе можно получить через `GetNativeSystemInfo()`.